# Cons of Titanium today?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I tried to find the updated information on Titanium cons, but they all range back to 2011 or 2012. They mention bad Android integration, lack of modules, etc. All of this is outdated today.

I know that Titanium has grown a lot since then, but I am still reluctant to use it in my next multi-platform project.

Can anyone using Titanium for the past years tell me what are it's cons and limitation TODAY? Ideally someone who's been using it for the last 2-3 years.

Comment: Guys, why is this off topic as I want to hear first-hand opinions from Titanium coders? We have similar topics on any other IDE or technology.